# org-plot has no effect

Tags: emacs, gnuplot, org-mode

I am following the instruction on http://orgmode.org/manual/Org_002dPlot.html to use org-plot. I have Gnuplot and Gnuplot mode installed.

I am trying this example

```
  #+PLOT: title:"Citas" ind:1 deps:(3) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]"
 | Sede      | Max cites | H-index |
 |-----------+-----------+---------|
 | Chile     |    257.72 |   21.39 |
 | Leeds     |    165.77 |   19.68 |
 | Sao Paolo |     71.00 |   11.50 |
 | Stockholm |    134.19 |   14.33 |
 | Morelia   |    257.56 |   17.67 |
```

Invoking `org-plot/gnuplot` has no effect, I just get this in the message buffer `gnuplot-mode 0.7-beta (gnuplot 5.0) -- report bugs with "C-c C-u"`

Any help is welcome
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with gnuplot, rather than org-mode; in particular, the terminal type might not be supported on your system. Switch to the *gnuplot* buffer in emacs and see if there is an error. You might also start a gnuplot session from the command line and copy all the commands from that buffer, as well as check the temporary file with the data. Unfortunately, org-plot/gnuplot deletes the data file at the first idle opportunity, so you might want to comment out this line in org-plot.el temporarily:

```
  (run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil #'delete-file data-file)
```

It's line 293 in my version. The contents of the file should be:

```
"Chile" 257.72  21.39 
"Leeds" 165.77  19.68
"Sao Paolo" 71.00   11.50
"Stockholm" 134.19  14.33
"Morelia"   257.56  17.67
```

and the *gnuplot* buffer should contain something like this:

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'qt'
gnuplot> reset
gnuplot> set title 'Citas'
gnuplot> set yrange [0:]
gnuplot> set datafile separator "\t"
gnuplot> plot '/tmp/org-plot14647Q7f' using 3:xticlabel(1) with histograms  title 'H-index'
```

Hope this helps.